# Unable to push to 2 different container registries with 2 different service accounts

Tags: gcloud, google-container-registry

I'm automating our build process.  Before push is executed, I run the following script that logs the correct service account in.

```
if [[ "${DEPLOY_ENV}" == "production" ]]; then
    gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file "$DIR/production-secret.json"
else
    gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file "$DIR/test-secret.json"
fi
```

However, no matter which login, I'm always pushing to our "test" account's registry when I execute this command

```
gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/talk-like-humans/api:${IMAGE_VERSION}
```

Is there another command I need to run to set my push endpoint to be in the correct account?

Thanks,
Todd

Answer (score 0):

The repository you push to is determined by the image name, not the credential used. Your command

`gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/talk-like-humans/api:${IMAGE_VERSION}`

means that you will always push an image called `api:${IMAGE_VERSION}` to the `talk-like-humans` repository (in the `gcr.io` registry). If both your test and production credentials have write access there, they will both succeed.

It sounds to me like you want something like this:

```
if [[ "${DEPLOY_ENV}" == "production" ]]; then
    gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file "$DIR/production-secret.json"
    REPO="${PROD_REPO}"
else
    gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file "$DIR/test-secret.json"
    REPO="${TEST_REPO}"
fi
`gcloud docker -- push "gcr.io/${REPO}/api:${IMAGE_VERSION}"`
```

In addition, I would revoke access from `${PROD_REPO}` for the service account in `test-secret.json` -- this way your dev process can't accidentally push to production.